# Bigquery iso8601 string to timestamp

Tags: sql, time, google-bigquery, iso8601

In my dataset I have a variable `duration` where there are 2 million rows of data in `ISO 8601` format. Example format: `PT21S` or `PT5M29S`, `PT1M16S`

I'm having a problem converting this string variable to time. At the moment I'm using the query:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(duration, r'[^\d]+') as time,
```

Through this query it is possible to distinguish whether the duration is in hours minutes or seconds. I would like to convert the string duration to time. I have used Regex and cast but without success.
When I try to convert the string to time I get the errors:

> "Invalid timestamp: '15S'"

> "Invalid timestamp: '1M'

> "Bad int64 value: PT11M16S"

The biggest problem I run into is that the the string is never the same.

Further string Examples:

```
PT48S
PT43M40S 
PT7M54S 
PT3M14S 
PT4H17M16S 
PT3M46S 
PT3H18M35S 
PT3H8M45S
```

Update:
I tried

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT (duration) as time_str FROM x
)
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN time_str LIKE 'PT%H%M%S' THEN PARSE_TIME('PT%HH%MM%SS', time_str)
    WHEN time_str LIKE 'PT%M%S' THEN PARSE_TIME('PT%MM%SS', time_str)
    WHEN time_str LIKE 'PT%S' THEN PARSE_TIME('PT%SS', time_str)
    ELSE NULL
  END
FROM data
```

I got the error:

> Mismatch between format character 'S' and string character 'H'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider below

```
select time_str,
  ( select parse_time('%H:%M:%S', string_agg(ifnull(lpad(val, 2, '0'), '00'), ':' order by offset))
    from unnest([
      regexp_extract(time_str, r'(\d+)H'), 
      regexp_extract(time_str, r'(\d+)M'), 
      regexp_extract(time_str, r'(\d+)S')
    ]) val with offset) time_time
from data
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would be ok:

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST(['PT48S', 'PT43M40S', 'PT7M54S', 'PT3M14S', 'PT4H17M16S', 'PT3M46S', 'PT3H18M35S', 'PT3H8M45S']) as time_str
)
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN time_str LIKE 'PT%H%M%S' THEN PARSE_TIME('PT%HH%MM%SS', time_str)
    WHEN time_str LIKE 'PT%M%S' THEN PARSE_TIME('PT%MM%SS', time_str)
    WHEN time_str LIKE 'PT%S' THEN PARSE_TIME('PT%SS', time_str)
    ELSE NULL
  END
FROM data
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  When I try the solution I get the error: Mismatch between format character 'S' and string character 'H'